# Simple code to check many checkbox android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have 20 checkbox and want to check is all checkbox is checked. 
I use the below case to check all using OR operator.

```
if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                   "Bro, try Android :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

But is there any optimized way to check whether all Checkbox is selected

Answer (score 1):

An optimised way :

- Maintain an int field in your activity which has a default value of 0.
- In your checkbox's onChecked listener, increment or decrement the value of the int field by 1 depending on whether it is checked or unchecked.
- If the value of the int field is equal to 20, that means all of the checkboxes are checked.

Alternatively, you could also run a loop with the same code you mentioned as the body.

Comment: Hi can u share the code pls. As am very new to android and also i want this to be performed on click of a button